# MySQL count id base on diffrent column value

Tags: zend-framework

Hey i wanna count all ids(this is alias ACTUAL_ENTRIES) which are not related with column rt.x_type in joined table . I use zend framework. Here is my whole ORM query.

```
$columns = array(
  'EV.id as EVENT_ID',
  'EV.name as EVENT_NAME',
  'DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(EV.start_time), "UTC", LO.time_zone), "%m/%e/%Y %a %r") as EVENT_START_DATE',
  'LO.time_zone as TIME_ZONE',
  'coalesce(EV.expected_entry, "") as EXPECTED_ENTRIES',
  $db->quoteInto('count(if(RT.x_type NOT IN ("CREDIT","EXTERNAL"),EN.id,0)) AS ACTUAL_ENTRIES'),
  $db->quoteInto('sum(IF(EN.type != ?, 1, 0)) AS ACTUAL_ATHLETES', Entry::ENTRY_TYPE_TEAM),
  $db->quoteInto('sum(IF(EN.type = ?, 1, 0)) AS ACTUAL_TEAMS', Entry::ENTRY_TYPE_TEAM),
  'coalesce(T.name,"") as TIMER_NAME',
  'coalesce(T.phone, "") as TIMER_PHONE',
  'coalesce(T.sales_region, "") as SALES_REGION'
);

$rows = $this->_readonlydb->select()
  ->from(array('EV' => 'event'),'')
  ->join(array('LO' => 'location'),'EV.location_id = LO.id','')
  ->joinLeft(array('RT'  => 'reg_transaction'), 
                   "RT.event_id = EV.id AND
                    (RT.is_test = 0 OR RT.is_test IS NULL) AND 
                    RT.x_response_code = " . RegTransaction::RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS . "", '')
  ->joinLeft(array('EN' => 'entry'), 'EN.trans_id = RT.id', '')
  ->joinLeft(array('T'  => 'organization'), 'T.id = EV.timer_id', '')
  ->where('EV.is_test_event = ?', 0)
  ->where("EN.status NOT IN (?)",   array(Entry::ENTRY_STATUS_WITHDRAWN, Entry::ENTRY_STATUS_NEW))
  ->where('YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(EV.start_time), 3) = ?', date("YW"))
  ->group('EV.id')
  ->columns($columns)
  ->query()
  ->fetchAll()
;
```

Important part is

```
 $db->quoteInto('count(if(RT.x_type NOT IN ("CREDIT","EXTERNAL"),EN.id,0)) AS ACTUAL_ENTRIES'),
```

This not working. can someone suggest me something

Comment: Have you developed an SQL query? If so, give it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 You can use zf2 expression.
  new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression( 'count(if(RT.x_type NOT IN ("CREDIT","EXTERNAL"),EN.id,0)) AS ACTUAL_ENTRIES')
 It works for me in zf2
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.